# How to select all td elements of a given table?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I would like to select with jQuery all td elements of a table given in myT variable. I do not want to select tds from inner tables. I need a cross-browser solution and it should work with thead, tbody and without them.

So I would like a sum of:

```
myT.find(">tbody>tr>td");
myT.find(">thead>tr>td");
myT.find(">tr>td"); // is this necessary?
// is there something missing?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might do it:

```
myT.find('>*>tr>td, >tr>td');
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
myT.find("td").not("td td");
```

Comment: Nice. I accepted Kae's solution though, because I think it might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
myT.children('tr td');
```

or

```
myT.children('tr td').not('td table');
```

[Children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tblMaint = $("#tbl1")
var tblInner = $("#tblInner").find("td");
alert(tblMaint.find("td").not(tblInner).length);
```

[JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pyccki/TrDyd/)